# Update stop order API Interactive Brokers Python

Tags: python, api

I have orders in the market and have verified the order ID. I am trying to update the stop order in the bracket using the code below. The output isn't giving any errors but my stp price isn't changing? I have verified the variables are being retrieved and stored properly via the print command. Here is what the order shows if I print it to the terminal.
3359.75
994.0
0,0,0: STP BUY 27@179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000 GTC

```
        if action == "UpdateStp":
            print("Received Update Stop Email") 
            AquaHiFloat = float(subparse[3])
            AquaLoFloat = float(subparse[4])
            AquaHi = AquaHiFloat 
            AquaLo = AquaLoFloat 
          
###################################Get Original Stop ID & Lot Size           
            print("Retrieve original Stop Id and lotsize from archive") 
            f=open("BuyStopOrder.txt", "r")
            if f.mode == 'r':
                BuyStopId =float(f.read())
                f.close()
            f=open("SellStopOrder.txt", "r")
            if f.mode == 'r':
                SellStopId =float(f.read())
                f.close()
                
            f=open("LotSize.txt", "r")
            if f.mode == 'r':
                lastlots =float(f.read())
                f.close()
            print(lastlots)
            print(SellStopId)


            class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
                def __init__(self):
                    EClient.__init__(self, self)

                def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
                    super().nextValidId(orderId)
                    self.nextorderId = orderId
                    print('The next valid order id is: ', self.nextorderId)

                def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFullPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId, whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
                    print('orderStatus - orderid:', orderId, 'status:', status, 'filled', filled, 'remaining', remaining, 'lastFillPrice', lastFillPrice)
    
                def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
                    print('openOrder id:', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ':', order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

                def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
                    print('Order Executed: ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId, execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)


            def run_loop():
                app.run()

            app = IBapi()
            app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)
            app.nextorderId = None

                #Start the socket in a thread
            api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
            api_thread.start()

                #Check if the API is connected via orderid
            while True:
                if isinstance(app.nextorderId, int):
                    print('connected')
                    break
                else:
                    print('waiting for connection')   
        
            if (OpenPos) < 0.0:
                print("Updating Short Postion Stop Order")
                mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                mail.ehlo()
                mail.starttls()
                mail.login(user,pwd)
                message = MIMEMultipart()
                message['From'] = user
                message['To'] = alertmail
                message['Subject'] = "Updated Short Position Stop Order"
                body=""
                message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
                sms = message.as_string()
                mail.sendmail(user,alertmail,sms)
                mail.close
                stop_order = Order()
                stop_order.parentId = SellStopId
                stop_order.action = 'BUY'
                stop_order.orderType = 'STP'
                stop_order.auxPrice = AquaHi 
                stop_order.totalQuantity = lastlots
                stop_order.outsideRth = True
                stop_order.tif = 'GTC'
                app.placeOrder(SellStopId, contract, stop_order)
                print(AquaHi)
                print(SellStopId)
                
            if (OpenPos) > 0.0:
                mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                mail.ehlo()
                mail.starttls()
                mail.login(user,pwd)
                message = MIMEMultipart()
                message['From'] = user
                message['To'] = alertmail
                message['Subject'] ="Updated Long Position Stop Order"
                body=""
                message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
                sms = message.as_string()
                mail.sendmail(user,alertmail,sms)
                mail.close
                print("Updating Long Position Stop Order")
                stop_order = Order()
                stop_order.parentId = BuyStopId
                stop_order.action = 'SELL'
                stop_order.orderType = 'STP'
                stop_order.auxPrice = AquaLo 
                stop_order.totalQuantity = lastlots
                stop_order.outsideRth = True
                stop_order.tif = 'GTC'      
                app.placeOrder(BuyStopId, contract, stop_order)
                print(AquaLo)
                print("  ")
            if (OpenPos) == 0.0:
                print("No Open Position Stop for Aqua to update")
            done=True
            app.disconnect()
```

Comment: So, just sending a new STP order updates the exiting one?

Answer (score 0):

Code works great but OrderID needs to be INT not Float

```
        if f.mode == 'r':
            BuyStopId =int(f.read())
            f.close()
        f=open("SellStopOrder.txt", "r")
        if f.mode == 'r':
            SellStopId =int(f.read())
            f.close()
```